# Seaborn passes kwargs to plt.boxplot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to use Seaborn to create a boxplot and a stripplot, as in [this example](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/horizontal_boxplot.html). However, the data points of the stripplot can be hard to read on top of the boxplot. My goal is to have an 'open' boxplot, like the ones made by a pandas DataFrame.plot(kind='box'). See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html). But I still want Seaborn's builtin grouping functionality.

My attempt has been to use the PatchArtist rather than the Line2D artist. From the [seaborn boxplot documentation](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html),

`kwargs : key, value mappings`

`Other keyword arguments are passed through to plt.boxplot at draw time.`

But passing `patch_artist = True` results in an error: `TypeError: boxplot() got multiple values for keyword argument 'patch_artist'`.

A minimal working example:

```
import seaborn as sns
data = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.boxplot(x='day', y='total_bill', data=data, **{'notch':True})
```

The above example shows that the kwargs are being passed properly to plt.boxplot(). The example below generates the `TypeError`.

```
import seaborn as sns
data = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.boxplot(x='day', y='total_bill', data=data, **{'patch_artist':True})
```

Is the `patch_artist` the best way to generate open boxplots? If so, how can I use it with seaborn?

Comment: That's correct. The typo's been fixed.

Comment: You can't set `patch_artist=True` because seaborn is already doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, seaborn returns the subplot axis that it just generated. We can directly set properties on the artists it creates.

A minimal example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = sns.load_dataset('tips')

ax = sns.boxplot(x='day', y='total_bill', data=data)

plt.setp(ax.artists, alpha=.5, linewidth=2, fill=False, edgecolor="k")

sns.stripplot(x='day', y='total_bill', data=data, jitter=True, edgecolor='gray')
```

This lets us manipulate each patch individually, while still using the `hue` variable in `sns.boxplot()` to group the data for us. Finally, the `stripplot` overlay sits on top of the box.

Comment: @mwaskom Thanks for the streamline/help!

Comment: By the way the easiest thing to do if you have a white background is just to change the palette to `["w"]` and the boxes will look "open".

Comment: A good idea, too. But your `darkgrid` theme looks too good! I can't go back to white backgrounds.