# How to edit properties of whiskers, fliers, caps, etc. in Seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot, seaborn

I have created a nested boxplot with an overlayed stripplot using the Seaborn package. I have seen answers on stackoverflow regarding how to edit ***box*** properties both for [individual boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206474/boxplot-colors-by-x-value-and-hues-differentiated-by-pattern/31214355#31214355) and for [all boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163622/seaborn-passes-kwargs-to-plt-boxplot) using ax.artists generated by sns.boxplot.

Is there any way to edit whisker, cap, flier, etc. properties using a similar method? Currently I have to manually edit values in the `restyle_boxplot` method of the `_BoxPlotter()` class in the seaborn -> categorical.py file to get from the default plot to the desired plot:

Default Plot:
[image: Default Plot]

Desired Plot:
[image: Desired Plot]

Here is my code for reference:

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()


ax1 = sns.boxplot(x="Facility", y="% Savings", hue="Analysis",
             data=totalSavings)

plt.setp(ax1.artists,fill=False) # <--- Current Artist functionality

ax1 = sns.stripplot(x="Facility", y="% Savings", hue="Analysis",
                    data=totalSavings, jitter=.05,edgecolor = 'gray',
                    split=True,linewidth = 0, size = 6,alpha = .6)

ax1.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=13)
ax1.set_xticklabels(['Test 1','Test 2','Test 3','Test 4','Test 5'], rotation=90)
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax1.set_ylabel('Percent Savings (%)', fontsize = 14)


handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
legend1 = plt.legend(handles[0:3], ['A','B','C'],bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), 
                     loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='12') 
fig1.set_size_inches(10,7)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**EDIT: Note that this method appears to no longer work for matplotlib versions >=3.5. See [the answer by @JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72333641/588071) for an up to date answer**

You need to edit the `Line2D` objects, which are stored in `ax.lines`.

Heres a script to create a boxplot (based on the example [here](https://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)), and then edit the lines and artists to the style in your question (i.e. no fill, all the lines and markers the same colours, etc.)

You can also fix the rectangle patches in the legend, but you need to use `ax.get_legend().get_patches()` for that.

I've also plotted the original boxplot on a second Axes, as a reference.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
    
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="Set1", ax=ax1)
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="Set1", ax=ax2)

for i,artist in enumerate(ax2.artists):
    # Set the linecolor on the artist to the facecolor, and set the facecolor to None
    col = artist.get_facecolor()
    artist.set_edgecolor(col)
    artist.set_facecolor('None')

    # Each box has 6 associated Line2D objects (to make the whiskers, fliers, etc.)
    # Loop over them here, and use the same colour as above
    for j in range(i*6,i*6+6):
        line = ax2.lines[j]
        line.set_color(col)
        line.set_mfc(col)
        line.set_mec(col)

# Also fix the legend
for legpatch in ax2.get_legend().get_patches():
    col = legpatch.get_facecolor()
    legpatch.set_edgecolor(col)
    legpatch.set_facecolor('None')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It doesnt work.

Comment: @Joe yes it seems something changes around matplotlib v3.5. See JohanC's answer for an up-to-date version

Answer (score 9):

For matplotlib 3.5 the rectangles for the boxes aren't stored anymore in `ax2.artists`, but in `ax2.patches`.  As the background of the subplot is also stored as a rectangular patch, the list of patches needs to be filtered.

The code below further makes a few adjustments:

- the exact number of lines belonging to one boxplot is counted, as depending on the boxplot options there can be a different number of lines
- `saturation=1` is used; seaborn prefers to add some desaturation to larger areas, but lines will be better visible with full saturation

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="Set1", ax=ax1)
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="Set1", saturation=1, ax=ax2)

box_patches = [patch for patch in ax2.patches if type(patch) == matplotlib.patches.PathPatch]
if len(box_patches) == 0:  # in matplotlib older than 3.5, the boxes are stored in ax2.artists
    box_patches = ax2.artists
num_patches = len(box_patches)
lines_per_boxplot = len(ax2.lines) // num_patches
for i, patch in enumerate(box_patches):
    # Set the linecolor on the patch to the facecolor, and set the facecolor to None
    col = patch.get_facecolor()
    patch.set_edgecolor(col)
    patch.set_facecolor('None')

    # Each box has associated Line2D objects (to make the whiskers, fliers, etc.)
    # Loop over them here, and use the same color as above
    for line in ax2.lines[i * lines_per_boxplot: (i + 1) * lines_per_boxplot]:
        line.set_color(col)
        line.set_mfc(col)  # facecolor of fliers
        line.set_mec(col)  # edgecolor of fliers

# Also fix the legend
for legpatch in ax2.legend_.get_patches():
    col = legpatch.get_facecolor()
    legpatch.set_edgecolor(col)
    legpatch.set_facecolor('None')
sns.despine(left=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot with lines]