# Change Box and Point Grouping Hue on Seaborn Boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Lets create an sns boxplot, per the documentation:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="Set3")
```

Produces a nice plot:

[image]

However, I want to be able to control each groups' colors.  I would like show smoker "yes" group as gray boxes and grey outlier points, and I would like smoker "no" groups to appear with green boxes and green outlier points.  How can I edit the underlying `matplotlib` ax object to change these attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the colors of the boxes seems best done by passing your own `palette` to `boxplot()`.  For changing the colors of the outliers ("fliers") by group, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36893152/1628638) included a solution.  Here the resulting code:

```
import seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips,
  palette=sns.color_palette(('.5', 'g')))

# each box in Seaborn boxplot is artist and has 6 associated Line2D objects
for i, box in enumerate(ax.artists):
  col = box.get_facecolor()
  # last Line2D object for each box is the box's fliers
  plt.setp(ax.lines[i*6+5], mfc=col, mec=col)

plt.show()
```

And the result:
[image: box plot with desired colors]

Comment: what is the `ax.lines[i*6+5]` argument on the second to last line?

Comment: Line2D object for all the fliers of box `i`.